# Division calculation within pivot table values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

Please see example below. The row headings (redacted) are defect types of a product. The column headings are the name of the products (redacted) and just below are the total sales of that product.  The values in the table are the number of each product that contain a given defect (e.g., there were 264 instances of the left-most product that contained the bottom row's defect).

[pivot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt3v4.jpg)

I'm trying to get defect rates, not counts, **so what I'd like to do is have each value in the table be divided by the total sales number at the top of its respective column**. Using the above example, I want that lower-left cell that says "264" to instead display the result of 264/120755.6522.

Copying the pivot table values and then pasting them into a new table and dividing the values is not an option because as you can see, there is a filter at the top, and I don't want to have to make a table for each filter. Also, the raw data (not shown) is constantly being updated, so copy-pasted tables would become out-of-date quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way of doing this, such that I did not need to create a new table, which was my main requirement.

1. Add 2 columns in the raw data.
2. The first column (labeled "Sales" in this case) needs to have the correct divisor. To do this, I created a VLOOKUP formula that checks another table for the product and returns the total sales. That other table would look like:

| Product | sales |
| --- | --- |
| Product1 | 500 |
| Product2 | 400 |
| etc... | so on |

Every row in the raw data that contains product 2 should now have an entry of 400 in the sales column, for example, if this is done correctly.

3. The other new column (call it "Defect Rate") just has a formula =1/[whatever the sales column cell is for that row]. So if the row pertains to product 2, the value in that cell will be 1/400.
4. Now in the pivot table, use the field "Defect Rate" and when you how to summarize the values, choose by sum rather than count.  This will add all those 1/sales to give you a % of sales, thus the accurate defect rate.

At this point you can now create a pivot chart which will dynamically resize as you change filters (my actual, previously unstated, end goal).

Answer (score 0):

Add one or more columns to the right of your pivot data.  Have the header copy the sales numbers `=D3` for example.  Then set the data to equal the cell to its left divided by the header.  Example with C6 set to =B6/C3 - using the arrow key to select cell B6 (shown in the formula line).  Adjust for your cell locations.  Copy and paste down the column.
[image: excel pivot table snip with added column]

Comment: This will work for me, thanks! I still wonder if there is a way to do it without creating a new table, but for now, I'm going with your answer.